# Is there a way to know a point in pacific ocean is on which side of International Date Line in openlayer map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, gis, openlayers

I mean the actual International Date Line rather than the 180 degree longitude line
[image: Actual International Date Line]

By comparing the longitude with 180 degree or -180 degree longitude line is not good enough for me, is there any way or tools that could help me to do that?

```
lonLat.lon > 180 || lonLat.lon < -180
```

Comment: Use timezone vector data as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/kml-timezones.html - this geojson may be more recently updated https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/blob/master/geojson/ne_10m_time_zones.geojson

Comment: @Mike thanks, not exactly the same but it helps